# Subfigure have problems putting figures in the same line

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am using the `IEEEtran` template, two columns. When I want to put 4 figures in the same line (spanning two columns) using the `\subfigure` package, with the width of each figure setting to `0.24\textwidth`, these four figures cannot be placed in the same line. (see below latex code and the resulting figure.)

```
\begin{figure*}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{1\textwidth}
  \subfigure[\footnotesize x1.]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x1.eps}
    \label{fig:x1}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfigure[\footnotesize x2.]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x2.eps}
    \label{fig:x2}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfigure[\footnotesize x3.]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x3.eps}
    \label{fig:x3}
  }
  \hfill
  \subfigure[\footnotesize x4.]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x4.eps}
    \label{fig:x4}
  }
  \vspace{-0.2cm}
   \caption{\footnotesize xxxx.}\label{xxxx}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

However, when I do not use the `\subfigure` package, 4 figures can be correctly reside in one line. (see below)

```
   \begin{figure*}[!t]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x1.eps}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}%
    \caption{\footnotesize x1.}
    \label{fig:x1}
  %\vspace{-0.2cm}%
  \end{minipage}
    \centering
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x2.eps}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}%
    \caption{\footnotesize x2.}\label{fig:x2}
  %\vspace{-0.2cm}%
  \end{minipage}
   \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x3.eps}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}%
    \caption{\footnotesize x3.}
    \label{fig:x3}
  %\vspace{-0.2cm}%
  \end{minipage}
    \centering
  \begin{minipage}[htp]{0.24\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{x4.eps}
    \vspace{-0.6cm}%
    \caption{\footnotesize x4.}\label{fig:x4}
  %\vspace{-0.2cm}%
  \end{minipage}
  \vspace{-0.3cm}%
\end{figure*}
```

[image]

**Why the same width leads to different formats?**

**Edit**: I have upload the tex and eps files to here: http://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=1594110695&uk=3776487005, which compose a MWE. Please open that link and click the button as shown in the figure below to download. (The opened page will be in Chinese.)

[image]

Comment: And don't use `[!t]` with starred figure environment. Let it handle by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `subfigure`, you're in horizontal mode, so you need to be careful of escaping your line ends. Where you have

```
\subfigure[\footnotesize x1.]{
  \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x1.eps}
  \label{fig:x1}
}
```

you insert an additional space character every time a line doesn't end with `%`, and this is inserting just enough space to cause the boxes to overfill the line; see below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \subfigure[x1.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x1.eps}%
    \label{fig:x1}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfigure[x2.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x2.eps}%
    \label{fig:x2}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfigure[x3.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x3.eps}%
    \label{fig:x3}%
  }%
  \hfill
  \subfigure[x4.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{x4.eps}%
    \label{fig:x4}%
  }%
  \caption{xxxx.}
  \label{xxxx}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

As a side-note, you shouldn't be manually changing the font size inside each caption. Use the `caption` package (etc.) to do this automatically across your whole document.

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't have any idea about the `horizontal mode` before, nor did I know `%` can be used in such a way. And I am sure that this is not the first time I am suggested not to manually change the font size. But I don't know how to use the `caption` package.

Comment: If you're using the IEEEtran class because you're submitting to a journal or conference, best not to adjust things like font style anyway since they'll do that themselves when they publish the paper.